# Creating Calendar table in Power BI where first date is beginning of financial year 4 years previous

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have created a calendar table using the DAX code below, but I am trying to swap out the date `"04/04/2000"` for a dynamic date, which is the first date of the financial year 4 years previous to todays date. Is this possible?

```
Date Table2 = CALENDAR(("04/01/2000"),TODAY())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Date Table2 = CALENDAR(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()-365*4);4;1);TODAY())
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to swap out the ; for , but works perfectly now! thank you :)

Comment: Yeah.. sorry, regional settings change the separator